# Xcode: copying static library target to new project

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I am trying to use the objective-c API provided by Google for Youtube using this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary).

The project provided has a target for creating a static library. The documentation asks to copy the target into my project instead of the static library it produces.

> The library project includes a target for building a static library for iOS apps. The static library target should be dragged into your application project's Build Phases "Link Binary with Libraries" list.

I am not able to do this. Is this what I am supposed to drag?

[image]

Since I could not find a way to drag the target, I went to the derived data folder and copied static library into the project. It worked but only partially. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

no you should drag library from left side (Project Navigator).

But in bottom of (Link Binary with Libraries) section presents `+` and `-` buttons that do the same functionality as dragging, so you also can add library with plus button

Also if you build this lib from source don't remember add it to `Target Dependency` section

Comment: but if I drag from the project navigator, is that not like copying the static library itself rather than the Target for static library?

Comment: yes, is not copying library, because library not exists in this time, compiler create it later in compilation time and copy to your project.